# Display UISliders value as %

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have a UILabel that is currently displaying the value on a UISlider as a value between 0 and 1 in increments of .1 (so it would display .1 or .2 or .3 etc up to 1).  However I want to display this value as a % out of 100, but I'm not quite familiar with formatting floating point numbers.  Here is the code I have right now:

```
sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [[f numberFromString:thresholdFile] floatValue]];
```

Comment: Just take the value and multiply it by 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha, this can be tricky....
From the [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) docs:

> .number
>   For e, E and f specifiers: this is the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point.

Thus, what you really want is this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %%", [mySlider value] * 100];
```

Let's break this down, shall we?

1. `%f`: Prints the first floating point number in the arguments list, which is:

   ```
   [mySlider value] * 100
   ```

   Notice the `* 100` part there, which converts a number in the range of `0 ... 1` to a range of `0 ... 100`. You may wish to call `round()` on this if you don't want a decimal percentage.
2. `%%`: Prints out an actual `%` character. This is because `printf` searches for switches that begin with the `%` character, and so if we had one verbatim in the string, it would throw a hissy fit. Thus, we escape that with another `%` (just like we would with a backslash), and it's fine.

Comment: I swear I didn't copy this. Your answer is much better.

Comment: @Dustin hey, don't sweat it, happens all of the time. I +1'd your answer too, seeing as it's correct :)

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III Can you give me the code if I don't want a decimal percentage. I just want the value be displayed between 0%-100%. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just take the value and multiply it by 100

```
sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %%",(/*name of slider*/.value)*100];
```